Proving that $\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \log X_n/\log n \le -1$ a.s. where $X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$
Let $X_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be independent random variables, uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. Show that
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1 \ \ \text{a.s.}$$
I added my solution below as an answer. I am not quite sure why this was downvoted.

We start by noticing
$$
\forall n. \exists k\ge n. a_n \le c \implies \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_n \le c
$$
Hence
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\{\frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1\right\}\right) \le\mathbb{P}\left(\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1\right)
$$
where the limit on the LHS is a set-theoretic limit. One can check
$$
\frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1 \iff X_n \le \frac{1}{n}
$$
We calculate
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_n \le \frac{1}{n}) = \int_0^{\frac{1}{n}}1 \ dx = \frac{1}{n}
$$
Therefore
$$
\sum_{n\ge 1} \mathbb{P}\left(\frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1\right) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n} = \infty
$$
Hence, using the second Borel-Cantelli lemma and the fact that $X_n$ are independent, we get
$$
1 = \mathbb{P}\left(\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left\{\frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1\right\}\right) \le \mathbb{P}\left(\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1\right) \le 1
$$
Thus
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{\log X_n}{\log n} \le -1 \ \ \text{a.s}
$$
Any suggestions for improving the proof are welcome!

It's not true that $\liminf(a_n)\leq c$ if and only if $a_n\leq c$ infinitely often. For example, think of $a_n=\frac{1}{n}$. What is true is that $\liminf(a_n)\leq c$ if and only if for any $\epsilon>0$ we have $a_n\leq c+\epsilon$ infinitely often.

That being said, if you prove that $\mathbb{P}(\frac{\log X_n}{\log n}\leq -1 \ \ \text{i.o})=1$ then the required probability, which is the probability of an even larger event, also has to be $1$.

@Mark Thank you, I missed that. I corrected the proof accordingly.
